# Is this XML able to be parsed?

Tags: python, xml, python-requests, xml-parsing

I'm trying to parse an XML response but have had no luck.

I'm using the python requests libary to connect to an API that returns XML.

From response.content I get:

```
{"GetQuestions":"<Questions><Question><QuestionId>393938<\/QuestionId><QuestionText>Please respond to the following statement:\"The assigned task was easy to complete\"<\/QuestionText><QuestionType>single<\/QuestionType><QuestionStatus>0<\/QuestionStatus><ExtendedType>0<\/ExtendedType><\/Question><Question><QuestionId>393939<\/QuestionId><QuestionText>Did you save your  datafor later? Why\/why not?<\/QuestionText><QuestionType>text<\/QuestionType><QuestionStatus>1<\/QuestionStatus><ExtendedType>0<\/ExtendedType><\/Question><Question><QuestionId>393940<\/QuestionId><QuestionText>Did you notice how much it cost to find the item? How much was it?<\/QuestionText><QuestionType>text<\/QuestionType><QuestionStatus>0<\/QuestionStatus><ExtendedType>0<\/ExtendedType><\/Question><Question><QuestionId>393941<\/QuestionId><QuestionText>Did you select ‘signature on form’? Why\/why not?<\/QuestionText><QuestionType>text<\/QuestionType><QuestionStatus>1<\/QuestionStatus><ExtendedType>0<\/ExtendedType><\/Question><Question><QuestionId>393942<\/QuestionId><QuestionText>Was it easy to find thethe new page? Why\/why not?<\/QuestionText><QuestionType>single<\/QuestionType><QuestionStatus>1<\/QuestionStatus><ExtendedType>4<\/ExtendedType><\/Question><Question><QuestionId>393943<\/QuestionId><QuestionText>Please enter your email. So that we can track your responses, we need you to provide this for each task.<\/QuestionText><QuestionShortCode>email<\/QuestionShortCode><QuestionType>text<\/QuestionType><QuestionStatus>1<\/QuestionStatus><ExtendedType>0<\/ExtendedType><\/Question><Question><QuestionId>393944<\/QuestionId><QuestionText>Why didn't you save your  datafor later?<\/QuestionText><QuestionType>text<\/QuestionType><QuestionStatus>0<\/QuestionStatus><ExtendedType>0<\/ExtendedType><\/Question><Question><QuestionId>393945<\/QuestionId><QuestionText>Why did you save your  datafor later?<\/QuestionText><QuestionType>single<\/QuestionType><QuestionStatus>0<\/QuestionStatus><ExtendedType>4<\/ExtendedType><\/Question><Question><QuestionId>393946<\/QuestionId><QuestionText>Did you save your  datafor later?<\/QuestionText><QuestionType>single<\/QuestionType><QuestionStatus>0<\/QuestionStatus><ExtendedType>0<\/ExtendedType><\/Question><Question><QuestionId>393947<\/QuestionId><QuestionText>Why didn't you select 'signature on form'?<\/QuestionText><QuestionType>text<\/QuestionType><QuestionStatus>0<\/QuestionStatus><ExtendedType>0<\/ExtendedType><\/Question><Question><QuestionId>393948<\/QuestionId><QuestionText>Why did you select 'signature on form'?<\/QuestionText><QuestionType>text<\/QuestionType><QuestionStatus>0<\/QuestionStatus><ExtendedType>0<\/ExtendedType><\/Question><Question><QuestionId>4444449<\/QuestionId><QuestionText>Did you select ‘signature on form’?<\/QuestionText><QuestionType>single<\/QuestionType><QuestionStatus>0<\/QuestionStatus><ExtendedType>0<\/ExtendedType><\/Question><Question><QuestionId>393950<\/QuestionId><QuestionText>Why wasn't it easy to find thethe new page?<\/QuestionText><QuestionType>single<\/QuestionType><QuestionStatus>0<\/QuestionStatus><ExtendedType>4<\/ExtendedType><\/Question><Question><QuestionId>393951<\/QuestionId><QuestionText>Was it easy to find thethe new page?<\/QuestionText><QuestionType>single<\/QuestionType><QuestionStatus>0<\/QuestionStatus><ExtendedType>0<\/ExtendedType><\/Question><Question><QuestionId>393952<\/QuestionId><QuestionText>Please enter your email addressSo that we can track your responses, we need you to provide this for each task<\/QuestionText><QuestionShortCode>email<\/QuestionShortCode><QuestionType>single<\/QuestionType><QuestionStatus>0<\/QuestionStatus><ExtendedType>4<\/ExtendedType><\/Question><\/Questions>"}
```

If I pass that directly to ElementTree :

```
ElementTree.fromstring(response.content)
```

It returns:

```
xml.etree.ElementTree.ParseError: not well-formed (invalid token): line 1, column 0
```

I remove from the start:  {"GetQuestions":

I remove from the end:   "}

Still returns a **xml.etree.ElementTree.ParseError.**

Is there something wrong with my approach or is it the XML?

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: The issue are the escape characters "\". You could try using: `etree.fromstring(d["GetQuestions"].replace("<\\", "<"))`

Comment: `I'm using the python requests libary to connect to an API that returns XML.` - this is not true - the API return a json string. Inside the json there is xml document

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can parse the xml but you need to do a minor cleanup before.

see below

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import requests 
# response is a dict with 1 entry
response = requests.get('api_url_goes_here').json()
# TODO - remove next line when you actually call the API
response = {"GetQuestions":"<Questions><Question><QuestionId>393938<\/QuestionId><QuestionText>Please respond to the following statement:\"The assigned task was easy to complete\"<\/QuestionText><QuestionType>single<\/QuestionType><QuestionStatus>0<\/QuestionStatus><ExtendedType>0<\/ExtendedType><\/Question><Question><QuestionId>393939<\/QuestionId><QuestionText>Did you save your  datafor later? Why\/why not?<\/QuestionText><QuestionType>text<\/QuestionType><QuestionStatus>1<\/QuestionStatus><ExtendedType>0<\/ExtendedType><\/Question><Question><QuestionId>393940<\/QuestionId><QuestionText>Did you notice how much it cost to find the item? How much was it?<\/QuestionText><QuestionType>text<\/QuestionType><QuestionStatus>0<\/QuestionStatus><ExtendedType>0<\/ExtendedType><\/Question><Question><QuestionId>393941<\/QuestionId><QuestionText>Did you select ‘signature on form’? Why\/why not?<\/QuestionText><QuestionType>text<\/QuestionType><QuestionStatus>1<\/QuestionStatus><ExtendedType>0<\/ExtendedType><\/Question><Question><QuestionId>393942<\/QuestionId><QuestionText>Was it easy to find thethe new page? Why\/why not?<\/QuestionText><QuestionType>single<\/QuestionType><QuestionStatus>1<\/QuestionStatus><ExtendedType>4<\/ExtendedType><\/Question><Question><QuestionId>393943<\/QuestionId><QuestionText>Please enter your email. So that we can track your responses, we need you to provide this for each task.<\/QuestionText><QuestionShortCode>email<\/QuestionShortCode><QuestionType>text<\/QuestionType><QuestionStatus>1<\/QuestionStatus><ExtendedType>0<\/ExtendedType><\/Question><Question><QuestionId>393944<\/QuestionId><QuestionText>Why didn't you save your  datafor later?<\/QuestionText><QuestionType>text<\/QuestionType><QuestionStatus>0<\/QuestionStatus><ExtendedType>0<\/ExtendedType><\/Question><Question><QuestionId>393945<\/QuestionId><QuestionText>Why did you save your  datafor later?<\/QuestionText><QuestionType>single<\/QuestionType><QuestionStatus>0<\/QuestionStatus><ExtendedType>4<\/ExtendedType><\/Question><Question><QuestionId>393946<\/QuestionId><QuestionText>Did you save your  datafor later?<\/QuestionText><QuestionType>single<\/QuestionType><QuestionStatus>0<\/QuestionStatus><ExtendedType>0<\/ExtendedType><\/Question><Question><QuestionId>393947<\/QuestionId><QuestionText>Why didn't you select 'signature on form'?<\/QuestionText><QuestionType>text<\/QuestionType><QuestionStatus>0<\/QuestionStatus><ExtendedType>0<\/ExtendedType><\/Question><Question><QuestionId>393948<\/QuestionId><QuestionText>Why did you select 'signature on form'?<\/QuestionText><QuestionType>text<\/QuestionType><QuestionStatus>0<\/QuestionStatus><ExtendedType>0<\/ExtendedType><\/Question><Question><QuestionId>4444449<\/QuestionId><QuestionText>Did you select ‘signature on form’?<\/QuestionText><QuestionType>single<\/QuestionType><QuestionStatus>0<\/QuestionStatus><ExtendedType>0<\/ExtendedType><\/Question><Question><QuestionId>393950<\/QuestionId><QuestionText>Why wasn't it easy to find thethe new page?<\/QuestionText><QuestionType>single<\/QuestionType><QuestionStatus>0<\/QuestionStatus><ExtendedType>4<\/ExtendedType><\/Question><Question><QuestionId>393951<\/QuestionId><QuestionText>Was it easy to find thethe new page?<\/QuestionText><QuestionType>single<\/QuestionType><QuestionStatus>0<\/QuestionStatus><ExtendedType>0<\/ExtendedType><\/Question><Question><QuestionId>393952<\/QuestionId><QuestionText>Please enter your email addressSo that we can track your responses, we need you to provide this for each task<\/QuestionText><QuestionShortCode>email<\/QuestionShortCode><QuestionType>single<\/QuestionType><QuestionStatus>0<\/QuestionStatus><ExtendedType>4<\/ExtendedType><\/Question><\/Questions>"}

# fetch the xml string and do a quick cleanup
xml = response['GetQuestions'].replace('<\/','</')
root = ET.fromstring(xml)
print(root)
```

output

```
<Element 'Questions' at 0x7f35c68919f0>
```

Comment: Hi @balderman, that worked it returned the root. I was specifying response.text instead of  just response as you had suggested. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

With that JSON string in the `response`:

```
xml.etree.ElementTree.fromstring(response.json()['GetQuestions'])
```

Comment: Hi @Joe, thanks for your suggestion, it returns a key error : KeyError: 'GetQuestions'

Comment: Then your response doesn't look like what's in your question.

Answer (score -1):

You can use BeautifulSoup to parse the xml content. When you create a variable you should write like this: `your_variable = BeautfilSoup(requests.text, features="xml" )`. That should work for you. Also try to validate your code so this one line became a full code. There must be errors. However it is really difficult to find out where as it is one line code. You can visit [Validator website](https://www.xmlvalidation.com)

Comment: Hi @IvanCompSci2003  I tried your suggestion. It returns: bs4.FeatureNotFound: Couldn't find a tree builder with the features you requested: xml. Do you need to install a parser library?

Comment: How about installing the lxml ( pip install lxml )

Comment: Also there might be a problem with "\" character, so try to .replace("\","")

Comment: from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
response = your_data
response = response["GetQuestions"].replace("/","")
data = BeautifulSoup(response,features="xml")
print(data)
Output it:

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Questions><Question><QuestionId>393938</QuestionId></Question></Questions>`

Comment: Hi @balderman, thanks for you suggestion. I tried it and it returns    xml =response.text['GetQuestions'].replace('<\/','</')
TypeError: string indices must be integers